# How to get domain/referer name from POST form that action points to other domain

Tags: php, html, forms, http

I have a form on *domain-x.com*. Which sends the form data to another **domain-y.com** service which handles it.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://domain-y.com/">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

How can i get the referer or to be sure that this form's request comes from *domain-x.com*?

I use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, but it not contains any information about domain-x.com

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` does not work

EDIT:
I don't want to change my form. The problem is somehow via request i should be able where the request comes from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i couldn't get by ex. Referer or any other identifier header from request was a lack of *SSL* certificate on my test server.

Which means in **form action** i had to change url from *http* to *https* and create SSL certificate

Answer (score 1):

You could add in a hidden field.

```
<input type='hidden' name='referrer' value='<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>'/>
```

It seems quite unorthodox to be posting a form to an entirely different domain however.

You can spoof `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` so either way isn't entirely reliable

Documentation on `HTTP_REFERER`

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Of course i can do it that way, but creating input which you can easily change is even worse

Comment: You can easily change HTTP_REFERRER

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing "Several software tools exist to facilitate referer spoofing in web browsers."

Comment: Maybe the referer is not the best solution, but somehow i should be able to identify where to request comes from

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't post to your own domain, and then via php forward it to domain-y? maybe via an API or a script you have created on domain-y to receive it?

Comment: Let's say the domain with form don't have backend nor js

Comment: Have you checked HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ? May be in there, but see update to answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194305/discussion-between-zbigniew-malcherczyk-and-zanderwar).

Comment: You can spoof every part of an http request because you can make one up on your own. Therefore, you can't trust any information that was sent anyway. Putting an origin identifier to the form is as good as any other method of tracking